# serverless framework: configuring a pre-existing lambda authenticator for HTTP API Gateway routes in serverless.yml

Tags: frameworks, serverless, serverless-framework, api-gateway

I would like to add a preexisting lambda authenticator to the routes of a preexisting http api gateway using the serverless framework. I have followed the docs, whereby I have specified the authorizer details under provider.httpApi (lines 15 to 18), and I have referenced the authorizer on the route(s) below (line 27 & 28). Though I get the error message:

> Cannot setup authorizers for externally configured HTTP API

What am I doing wrong here? It must be for a HTTP API gateway and not a REST API gateway as thats what the current infra is configured as. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using an externally configured HTTP API (I'm guessing from the `id` being set). In such a situation, you cannot configure authorizers in this manner, you can only do so when you're provisioning HTTP API as a part of your serverless service. What you can do there, is to setup a  shared authorizer in a more manual way as described in docs here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#shared-authorizer

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when researching how to use API gateway authorizers and serverless framework. I was terraforming the API gateway therefore needed to terraform the authorizer as well. When created, I stashed the authorizer ID in a parameter store entry. This is a 6 character alphanumeric value such as `tw9qgj`. I then referenced the parameter as follows:

```
custom:
  authorizerId: ${ssm:api_gateway_authoriser}
```

Then added the following block to each API e.g.

```
      - httpApi:
          path: /protected
          method: get
          authorizer:
            id: ${self:custom.authorizerId}
```